# Webpage for recording user data and creating visualisations from data

Tags: javascript, visualization, velo

Is there a way to record user data using a form, and then display visualisations of the user's data against an already available database? I tried Wix but I don't think their form submissions allow data to be manipulated and shown in-site. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's definitely doable on Wix, but we'd need more detail as to what exactly you're trying to do to say for sure and point you in the right direction.